# Flex List selected entire list by default

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am currently working on a project in Flex and I am having a hard time having a list's contents ALL be selected by default. Wondering how to do this. Appreciate any help.

`<mx:List id="list" dataProvider="{dp}" allowMultipleSelection="true"/>`

I'm just trying to have the list all selected.

Comment: What list do you use? Spark or MX? Can you post your code to understand where is your problem?

Comment: @Constantiner I don't really know where to start to have them all selected so I don't really have much code to show.

Comment: What is your data provider? `Array`, `ArrayCollection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use something like the following:

```
<mx:List id="list" dataProvider="{dp}" allowMultipleSelection="true" 
    creationComplete="event.currentTarget.selectedItems = event.currentTarget.dataProvider.source"/>
```

Comment: Can you extract `creationComplete` handler into separate ActionScript method and trace the value of `event.currentTarget.dataProvider.source`?

Comment: Okay I took a look at the dataProvider in the creationComplete and it is null at that time, but I checked the init and there it has it's values. I tried the line about with the init and it didn't work. Not sure why...

Comment: What is `init`? The point is the following. At the moment when your `dp` is initialized and fully filled with data you need to set `list`'s `selectedItems` with `dp.source`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying many different variations to get the list to be all selected. This is the one that ended up working.

`var arr:Array = new Array();`

`for (var i:Number = 0; i < (list.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).length; i++) {`

`arr[i] = i;`

`}`

`list.selectedIndices = arr;`